# SQL - How do I create a table with values as columns and a new format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which currently looks a bit like this-

```
CASEID  ¦  FORMNAME  ¦  NAME  ¦  VALUE

601554  ¦  CASEFORM  ¦  Mond  ¦  AAAA
601554  ¦  CASEFORM  ¦  Tues  ¦  BBBB
601554  ¦  CASEFORM  ¦  Wedn  ¦  CCCC
601554  ¦  CASEFORM  ¦  Thur  ¦  DDDD
```

I now want to create a new table in SQL that will copy the data and change the format of it entirely as follows-

```
CASEID  ¦  FORMNAME  ¦  Mond  ¦  Tues  ¦  Wedn  ¦  Thur

601554  ¦  CASEFORM  ¦  AAAA  ¦  BBBB  ¦  CCCC  ¦  DDDD
```

The original table has about 400 lines, so the new table is going to need 400 columns.

My SQL knowledge is certainly limited, but I can always blunder my way to a solution when I need one.  In this case however I don't even know where to begin.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just want to say thanks to everyone who has posted so far.  I'm reading up on all of your suggestions.  Cheers.

Comment: Looks like 'rs' provided as an answer the amendment I was going to make to mine:  dynamic SQL using PIVOT feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this query:

```
create table NewTable(CASEID int,  FORMNAME varchar(255))
go

insert into NewTable select distinct caseid,formname from OldTable
go

select  distinct 'alter table NewTable add ' +[name]+ ' varchar(255)'  from oldtable
```

and then copy the results and run them.

Then run this query:

```
select distinct 'update NewTable set ' +Name+ ' = ''' + Value +''' where caseid = ' +cast(caseid as varchar(20))+
' and FORMNAME = '''+Formname+''''
from oldtable
```

and then copy the results and run them.

Edit: Added automated version:

```
create table NewTable(CASEID int,  FORMNAME varchar(255)) 
go 
insert into NewTable select distinct caseid,formname from OldTable 
go
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(max)
set @query = ''
select  @query = @query + 'alter table NewTable add ' +[name]+ ' varchar(255);'  from (select distinct name from oldtable )c
exec (@query)
set @query = ''
select @query = @query+ 'update NewTable set ' +Name+ ' = ''' + Value +''' where caseid = ' +cast(caseid as varchar(20))+ ' and FORMNAME = '''+Formname+'''' 
from  (select distinct  Name, Value, Caseid, FormName from OldTable)c
exec (@query)
```

Comment: This actually does the job perfectly thanks, however the two manual elements pose me a problem as I need to automate the whole process to be triggered automatically. Do you know of a good way to do this?  I am working with eForms & web services, and was hoping to trigger this process via web service/stored procedure at the point of submission of the eForm.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Kevin, and thanks to everyone else. I worked on this option first merely as it appeared to be the simplest in terms of my level of SQL knowledge. Happily it worked perfectly for what I needed and will now allow me to make a huge difference to my organisation's reporting of eform data.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a metamodel.

What you need to do is to loop on your METAMODEL table and build a custom ALTER statement for each row found corresponding to whatever your definition of a MODEL column is.

I also see you also want to transform the values. If that is so, build the DML statement on the fly as well in the same loop, and execute them afterwards so your destination model is finished building.

**Links:**

alter table mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

cursors mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

---

On the other hand, this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN ', t.name, ' VARCHAR(256);') FROM mytable t
```

will return the alter table statements you need to manually add these columns. You can use this as a model to build the next query to add up the values to your table later.

Rgds.

Answer (score 1):

For Sql Server might want to look at the pivot feature. Heres a sample that matches your scenario and outputs the results you wanted...

```
declare @data table (CASEID int, FORMNAME varchar(20), NAME varchar(20), VALUE varchar(20))
insert into @data values
(601554, 'CASEFORM', 'Mond', 'AAA'),
(601554, 'CASEFORM', 'Tues', 'BBB'),
(601554, 'CASEFORM', 'Wedn', 'CCC'),
(601554, 'CASEFORM', 'Thur', 'DDD')

SELECT *
FROM @data
PIVOT
(
  MAX(VALUE)
  FOR [NAME] IN ([Mond],[Tues],[Wedn],[Thur])
)
AS data
```

Comment: Only problem I see with this query is that he has to type out 400 column names

Comment: Why would you type them out? I'd make use of Visual Studios regex Search and Replace feature. I'll provide an answer update...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know exact number of columns you can use this:

```
DECLARE @columns varchar(max)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast([Name] as varchar(100)) + ']', 
                 '[' + cast([Name] as varchar(100))+ ']')           
    FROM   @data1 

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM @data1 '
SET @query = @query  + '            
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(VALUE) FOR [NAME] IN (' + @columns + ')
            )
             AS p'                                  

EXEC @query
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, that's a really strange requirement! 
Being said that, what you need is a pivot query. Details can be found at [Ask Tom - Pivot Query](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740)

Comment: It is a strange one.  I'm trying to strip data out of a really weird table in a really weird system, and trying to get it into a usable format to put into a Business Objects universe.